# Unable to scrape a class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am currently trying to make a web scraper using python. The objective I have is for my web scraper to find the name and the price of a stock. Here is my code:

```py
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MA?p=MA&.tsrc=fin-srch')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
stock_name = soup.find({ "class" : "D(ib) Fz(18px)"})
print(stock_name)
```

but when i run it i get this:

```
C:\Users\baribal\Desktop>py web_scraper.py
None
```

thank you in advance!

Comment: It seems like the web use js for get the information.... .Maybe you will need selenium

Comment: Depending on the webpage, you might not need javascript after all! Take a look at the "Network" tab of your browser's developer tools while the page is loading. It might be that the information is taken from a basic Ajax request, which is very easy to replicate. However it might get complicated and if it does consider using selenium

Answer (score 0):

Your request just gives you the raw HTML of the webpage. The elements you are trying to retrieve are React components that are rendered **in the browser after the HTML source text is loaded**.

You need to use a headless browser like Selenium instead.